# Apply function to result of numpy.where

Tags: python, numpy

Assume I have an array:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,0,-1,-2,3,4]
```

Using `np.where(a < 0)` it returns a list of indices which elements a are < 0

How to apply a function for those elements of a?

Answer (score 2):

If you convert your list into a numpy array, it gets easier: you can index arrays with boolean arrays:

```
In [2]: a = np.asarray([1,2,3,4,0,-1,-2,3,4])

In [3]: a[a < 0]
Out[3]: array([-1, -2])

In [4]: np.sin(a[a < 0])
Out[4]: array([-0.84147098, -0.90929743])

In [5]: a[a < 0]**2
Out[5]: array([1, 4])
```

The key here is that `a < 0` is an array itself:

```
In [6]: a < 0
Out[6]: array([False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: If you want to return the full array, you can assign the values as well such as: `a[a<0] = a[a<0]**2`.

Comment: should return 

[1,2,3,4,0,-0.84147098, -0.90929743,3,4]

and not only an array of values for elements  < 0

Answer (score 2):

In general I would recommend following @ev-br approach using boolean masks. But it's also possible with [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) if you use all three arguments. The second argument specifies the value chosen at the indices where the condition is `True` and the third where it's `False`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4,0,-1,-2,3,4])
>>> np.where(a < 0, 1000, a)   # replace values below 0 with 1000
array([   1,    2,    3,    4,    0, 1000, 1000,    3,    4])
```

If you want to apply a numpy-ufunc (for example `np.sin`) just replace the `1000`:

```
>>> np.where(a < 0, np.sin(a), a)
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  0., -0.84147098, -0.90929743,  3.,  4.])
```

---

Alternativly (this requires that the array already has the correct dtype to store the result of the function) you could use the indices returned by `np.where` to apply the result on:

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4,0,-1,-2,3,4], dtype=float) # must be floating point now
>>> idx = np.where(a < 0)
>>> a[idx] = np.sin(a[idx])
>>> a
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  0., -0.84147098, -0.90929743,  3.,  4.])
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this ought to work:

```
square = lambda x: x**2
applied_func_array = [square(x) for x in a if x < 0]
```

Or with `numpy.vectorize`:

```
vec_square = np.vectorize(square)
vec_square(less_than_zero)
```

Which yields:

```
Out[220]: 
array([[1],
       [4]])
```

Comment: Thank you but I want to apply a function to elements with indces less_than_zero

Comment: What kind of function?

Comment: any given function wich takes one argument for example
f =  lambda x: x * 2

Answer (score -1):

I don't work with `numpy` a lot but did you mean something along these lines?

```
my_arr = np.array(a)

def my_func(my_array):
    for elem in np.where(my_array < 0):
       my_array[elem] =  my_array[elem] + 1 * 3
       return my_array

np.apply_along_axis(my_func, 0, my_arr)
rray([1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 2, 1, 3, 4])
```